# Including a groovy script in another groovy

Tags: groovy

I have read [how to simply import a groovy file in another groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738118/how-to-simply-import-a-groovy-file-in-another-groovy-script)

I want to define common functions in one groovy file and call those functions from other groovy files.

I understand this would be using Groovy like a scripting language i.e, I dont need classes/objects. I am trying to something like dsl that can be done in groovy. All variables will be asserted from Java and I want to execute groovy script in a shell.

Is this possible at all ? Can someone provide some example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load script from groovy script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004303/load-script-from-groovy-script)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
evaluate(new File("../tools/Tools.groovy"))
```

Put that at the top of your script.  That will bring in the contents of a groovy file (just replace the file name between the double quotes with your groovy script).

I do this with a class surprisingly called "Tools.groovy".

Comment: The filename needs to conform to Java's class naming rules for this to work.

Comment: Question - How can I pass arguments to the script I'm evaluating using this syntax?

Comment: @steve You can't, but you can define a function in that script which you call with arguments

Comment: Is it possible to get a return value from the script called with 'evaluate'?

Comment: @IanTait, you'd be better off calling it directly as an executable process.  For instance, file `/home/user/test.groovy` contains `println 12`, you would get that value from a different groovy script by coding `"groovy /home/user/test.groovy".execute().text` within your main script.

Comment: It doesn't work ... script is well evaluated but no declaration exists in caller scope (def, class, etc.)

Comment: You must return an object from call one, then assign evaluate result to a variable.

Comment: [Using shell.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9004842/321013) works better for me.

Comment: @MartinBa, would you explain why shell.parse is better for you than evaluate please?

Comment: @xpt - sorry it's been 7 years since I wrote that comment and I don't do much with Groovy. But I run my scripts in the context of a Jenkins instance - maybe evaluate doesn't work in Jenkins, or I didn't want to immediately run it back then. (parse doesn't run the code - I think evaluate does(?)

Answer (score 47):

As of Groovy 2.2 it is possible to declare a base script class with the new `@BaseScript` AST transform annotation.

Example:

**file MainScript.groovy**:

```
abstract class MainScript extends Script {
    def meaningOfLife = 42
}
```

**file test.groovy**:

```
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
@BaseScript MainScript mainScript

println "$meaningOfLife" //works as expected
```

Comment: I keep getting "unable to resolve class" when using this method. What would you recommend I do? Is there any way of importing custom classes into another groovy script?

Comment: I don't know how it could work. Where you give path to `MainScript.groovy`?

Answer (score 46):

Another way to do this is to define the functions in a groovy class and parse and add the file to the classpath at runtime:

```
File sourceFile = new File("path_to_file.groovy");
Class groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile);
GroovyObject myObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: This solution actually worked best for me.  When I tried using the accepted answer, I got an error saying that my main groovy script was unable to resolve the class defined in the evaluated script. For what it's worth...

Comment: I tried several different approaches that were posted on SO and only this worked. The others threw errors about not being able to resolve the class or the methods.  This is the version I'm using version Groovy Version: 2.2.2 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7.

Comment: This worked great.  Be sure to use `GroovyObject` explicitly, that's not a placeholder for your own class name.

Comment: Still I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Comment: Life saver. Thank you mate!!

Answer (score 32):

I think that the best choice is to organize utility things in form of groovy classes, add them to classpath and let main script refer to them via import keyword.

Example:

scripts/DbUtils.groovy

```
class DbUtils{
    def save(something){...}
}
```

scripts/script1.groovy:

```
import DbUtils
def dbUtils = new DbUtils()
def something = 'foobar'
dbUtils.save(something)
```

running script:

```
cd scripts
groovy -cp . script1.groovy
```

Comment: I wonder how this would work if you have a directory structure like with `lib` and `src` directories

Answer (score 12):

How about treat the external script as a Java class? Based on this article: https://www.jmdawson.net/blog/2014/08/18/using-functions-from-one-groovy-script-in-another/

**getThing.groovy**  The external script

```
def getThingList() {
    return ["thing","thin2","thing3"]
}
```

**printThing.groovy**  The main script

```
thing = new getThing()  // new the class which represents the external script
println thing.getThingList()
```

**Result**

```
$ groovy printThing.groovy
[thing, thin2, thing3]
```

Comment: Wouldn't work if you are running your script outside the source repository

Comment: what if getThing.groovy is in another folder?

Answer (score 10):

The way that I do this is with `GroovyShell`.

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def Util = shell.parse(new File('Util.groovy'))
def data = Util.fetchData()
```

Comment: This would give an error if multiple scripts are using the same 3rd party library.
Eg., if more than 1 script has below code:

@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.5')
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter

To solve this I had to use Object as the type instead of the actual type and need to remove the @Grab statement from other scripts (that are referenced in the main script).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a complete example of including one script within another.
Just run the Testmain.groovy file
Explanatory comments included because I'm nice like that ;]

**Testutils.groovy**

```
// This is the 'include file'
// Testmain.groovy will load it as an implicit class
// Each method in here will become a method on the implicit class

def myUtilityMethod(String msg) {
    println "myUtilityMethod running with: ${msg}"
}
```

**Testmain.groovy**

```
// Run this file

// evaluate implicitly creates a class based on the filename specified
evaluate(new File("./Testutils.groovy"))
// Safer to use 'def' here as Groovy seems fussy about whether the filename (and therefore implicit class name) has a capital first letter
def tu = new Testutils()
tu.myUtilityMethod("hello world")
```

Comment: Bravo! NB, can also just use the simple `import Testutils` instead of the evaluate new File. Tested fine.

Answer (score 8):

Groovy doesn't have an import keyword like typical scripting languages that will do a literal include of another file's contents (alluded to here: [Does groovy provide an include mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264696/does-groovy-provide-an-include-mechanism)). 
 Because of its object/class oriented nature, you have to "play games" to make things like this work. One possibility is to make all your utility functions static (since you said they don't use objects) and then perform a static import in the context of your executing shell. Then you can call these methods like "global functions". 
 Another possibility would be using a Binding object (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) while creating your Shell and binding all the functions you want to the methods (the downside here would be having to enumerate all methods in the binding but you could perhaps use reflection).  Yet another solution would be to override `methodMissing(...)` in the delegate object assigned to your shell which allows you to basically do dynamic dispatch using a map or whatever method you'd like.

Link is now dead: <s>Several of these methods are demonstrated here: http://www.nextinstruction.com/blog/2012/01/08/creating-dsls-with-groovy/.  Let me know if you want to see an example of a particular technique</s>.

Comment: this link is now dead

Answer (score 3):

Groovy can import other groovy classes exactly like Java does. Just be sure the extension of the library file is .groovy.

```
$ cat lib/Lib.groovy
package lib
class Lib {
   static saySomething() { println 'something' }
   def sum(a,b) { a+b }
}

$ cat app.gvy
import lib.Lib
Lib.saySomething();
println new Lib().sum(37,5)

$ groovy app
something
42
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of @grahamparks and @snowindy answers with a couple of modifications is what worked for my Groovy scripts running on Tomcat:

Utils.groovy

```
class Utils {
    def doSth() {...}
}
```

MyScript.groovy:

```
/* import Utils --> This import does not work. The class is not even defined at this time */
Class groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(new File("full_path_to/Utils.groovy")); // Otherwise it assumes current dir is $CATALINA_HOME
def foo = groovyClass.newInstance(); // 'def' solves compile time errors!!
foo.doSth(); // Actually works!
```

Comment: I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Answer (score 0):

For late-comers, it appears that groovy now support the `:load file-path` command which simply redirects input from the given file, so it is now trivial to include library scripts.

It works as input to the groovysh & as a line in a loaded file:
`groovy:000> :load file1.groovy`

file1.groovy can contain:
`:load path/to/another/file
invoke_fn_from_file();`

Comment: Can you expand on this please? Where is this in the docs? Where do i put `:load file-path`?

Comment: Well, it works as input to the groovysh & as a line in a loaded file:  <br/>
`groovy:000> :load file1.groovy`

file1.groovy can contain:  <br/>
`:load path/to/another/file`

Comment: I found [load in the docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#GroovyShell-load). If i understand correctly, it *only* works with groovysh?

Comment: This will not work with the path defined inside a variable, though, would it?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I have come to the conclusion that the following approach seems the best.

**some/subpackage/Util.groovy**

```
@GrabResolver(name = 'nexus', root = 'https://local-nexus-server:8443/repository/maven-public', m2Compatible = true)
@Grab('com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3')
@Grab('com.google.guava:guava:23.0')
@GrabExclude('com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations')

import com.google.common.base.Strings

class Util {
    void msg(int a, String b, Map c) {
        println 'Message printed by msg method inside Util.groovy'
        println "Print 5 asterisks using the Guava dependency ${Strings.repeat("*", 5)}"
        println "Arguments are a=$a, b=$b, c=$c"
    }
}
```

**example.groovy**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
Class clazz = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass("${new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent}/some/subpackage/Util.groovy" as File)
GroovyObject u = clazz.newInstance()
u.msg(1, 'b', [a: 'b', c: 'd'])
```

In order to run the `example.groovy` script, add it to your system path and type from any directory:

```
example.groovy
```

The script prints:

```
Message printed by msg method inside Util.groovy
Print 5 asterisks using the Guava dependency *****
Arguments are a=1, b=b, c=[a:b, c:d]
```

The above example was tested in the following environment: `Groovy Version: 2.4.13 JVM: 1.8.0_151 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`

The example demonstrates the following:

- How to use a `Util` class inside a groovy script.
- A `Util` class calling the `Guava` third party library by including it as a `Grape` dependency (`@Grab('com.google.guava:guava:23.0')`).
- The `Util` class can reside in a subdirectory.
- Passing arguments to a method within the `Util` class.

Additional comments/suggestions:

- Always use a groovy class instead of groovy script for reusable functionality within your groovy scripts. The above example uses the Util class defined in the Util.groovy file. Using groovy scripts for reusable functionality is problematic. For example, if using a groovy script then the Util class would have to be instantiated at the bottom of the script with `new Util()`, but most importantly it would have to be placed in a file named anything but Util.groovy. Refer to [Scripts versus classes](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_scripts_versus_classes) for more details about the differences between groovy scripts and groovy classes.
- In the above example I use the path `"${new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent}/some/subpackage/Util.groovy"` instead of `"some/subpackage/Util.groovy"`. This will guarantee that the `Util.groovy` file will always be found in relation to the groovy script's location (`example.groovy`) and not the current working directory. For example, using `"some/subpackage/Util.groovy"` would result in searching at `WORK_DIR/some/subpackage/Util.groovy`.
- Follow the Java class naming convention to name your groovy scripts. I personally prefer a small deviation where the scripts start with a lower letter instead of a capital one. For example, `myScript.groovy` is a script name, and `MyClass.groovy` is a class name. Naming `my-script.groovy` will result in runtime errors in certain scenarios because the resulting class will not have a valid Java class name.
- In the JVM world in general the relevant functionality is named [JSR 223: Scripting for the Java](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223). In groovy in particular the functionality is named [Groovy integration mechanisms](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html). In fact, the same approach can be used in order to call any [JVM language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) from within Groovy or Java. Some notable examples of such JVM languages are Groovy, Java, Scala, JRuby, and JavaScript (Rhino).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @snowindy that the cleanest way is to probably organize the code to Groovy classes.

You can also use Groovy's function call syntax by making the methods `static` and then `static import` ing them. This will give you a function for nearly all intents and purposes.

Simple example:
`Foo.groovy`:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Foo {
    static def dofoo() {
        println("foo")
    }
}
```

`bar.groovy`:

```
import static Foo.dofoo

dofoo()
```

Execute with `groovy bar.groovy`