# groovy win cmd line class and script

Tags: java, windows, class, groovy

I'm trying to run a groovy(2.4.3) script on windows that calls a goovy class  xxxxx.groovy. I've tried a number of variations using classpath and various scripts, some examples below, always getting MultipleCompliationErrorsException.... unable to resolve class

classfile is   firstclass.groovy

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

class firstclassstart {

       def  wluid,  wlpwd,  wlserver, port

       private wlconnection, connectString, jmxConnector, Filpath, Filpass, Filname, OSRPDpath, Passphrase

       // object constructor
       firstclassstart(wluid, wlpwd, wlserver, port) {            
           this.wluid = wluid
           this.wlpwd = wlpwd
           this.wlserver = wlserver
           this.port = port

            }

       def isFile(Filpath) {
           // Create a File object representing the folder 'A/B'
           def folder = new File(Filpath)

           if (!org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.isExtension(Filpath, "txt")) {
               println "bad extension"
               return false
           } else if (!folder.exists()) {
               // Create all folders up-to and including B
               println " path is wrong"
               return false
           } else
               println "file found"
           return true
       }
   }
```

cmd line script test.groovy

```
import firstclass
def sample = new firstclass.firstclassstart("weblogic", "Admin123", "x.com", "7002")
//def sample = new firstclassstart("weblogic", "Admin123", "x.com", "7002")
sample.isFile("./firstclass.groovy")

..\groovy -cp "firstclass.groovy;commons-io-1.3.2.jar" testfc.groovy
```

script test.groovy

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse(new File('mylib/firstclass.groovy'))
firstclass sample = new script.firstclass("uid", "pwd", "url", "port")
sample.getstatus()

c:>groovy test.groovy
```

script test.groovy v2   put firstclass.groovy  in directory test below script

```
import test.firstclass
firstclass sample = new script.firstclass("uid", "pwd", "url", "port")
sample.getstatus()

c:>groovy test.groovy
```

just looking for a bullet proof, portable way to oranize my java classes, .groovy classess, etc. and scripts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do using for example your first approach:

```
groovy -cp mylib/firstclass.groovy mylib/test.groovy
```

However I see some problems in your code which are probably causing `MultipleCompliationErrorsException`.

1. Since you're including firstclass.groovy in your classpath, you've to add the `import firstclass` in the `test.groovy`.
2. Why are you using `script.firstclass` in `test.groovy`? you're class is called simply `firstclass`.
3. In your `firstclass.groovy` you're using `import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils` and probably other, however you're not including it in the classpath.

So finally I think that, you've to change your `test.groovy` for something like:

```
import firstclass
firstclass sample = new firstclass("uid", "pwd", "url", "port")
sample.getstatus()
```

And in your command add the remaining includes for [apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to the classpath.

```
groovy -cp "mylib/firstclass.groovy;commons-io-2.4.jar;" mylib/testexe.groovy
```

Hope this helps,

**UPDATE BASED ON OP CHANGES:**

After the changes you've some things wrong, I try to enumerate it:

1. If your file is called `firstclass.groovy` your class must be `class firstclass` not `class firstclassstart`.
2. In your `test.groovy` use `new firstclass` not `new firstclass.firstclassstart`.

So the thing is, your code must be:

class file `firstclass.groovy`:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

class firstclass {

   def  wluid,  wlpwd,  wlserver, port

   private wlconnection, connectString, jmxConnector, Filpath, Filpass, Filname, OSRPDpath, Passphrase

   // object constructor
   firstclass(wluid, wlpwd, wlserver, port) {            
       this.wluid = wluid
       this.wlpwd = wlpwd
       this.wlserver = wlserver
       this.port = port

        }

   def isFile(Filpath) {
       // Create a File object representing the folder 'A/B'
       def folder = new File(Filpath)

       if (!org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.isExtension(Filpath, "txt")) {
           println "bad extension"
           return false
       } else if (!folder.exists()) {
           // Create all folders up-to and including B
           println " path is wrong"
           return false
       } else
           println "file found"
       return true
   }
}
```

script `test.groovy`:

```
import firstclass
def sample = new firstclass("weblogic", "Admin123", "x.com", "7002")
sample.isFile("./firstclass.groovy")
```

Finally the command to execute it:

```
groovy -cp "firstclass.groovy;commons-io-1.3.2.jar" test.groovy
```

With this changes your code must works, I try it and works as expected.

Comment: 1) ok; 2) my typo from another try; 3) ok  I'm still getting an error on the import statement.  I tried adding ../lib/groovy-2.4.34.jar to the cp and same thing.  I also tried evaluate(new File("mylib/firstclass.groovy"))  from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy.  With this I get 2 errors 1 pointing to sample and one pointing to new.

Comment: I get 5: unable to resolve firstclass.firstclassstart with the ^ under new; I changed the syntax slightly line2 in testfc is  def sample = new firstclass("uid", "pwd", "url", "port").   I simplifed the setup and put everything in the same directory and ran ..\groovy -cp "firstclass.groovy;commons-io-1.3.2.jar" testfc.groovy  I tried import fisrtclassstart and import firstclass.firstclassstart.

Comment: @user3120960 I update my answer based on your changes, take a look on it `:)`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch; that does work.  The thing that was confusing me is in my original code in IntelligjIDEA, I was getting a duplicate class error.  I now figured out that this was because of my placement of Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("") before the class statement.

Comment: @user3120960 perfect that now it works, nice to help you `:)`