# Expression evaluation for the transform script file location

Tags: spring-xd

Basically looking to parameterize the selected groovy transformation file based on message characteristics...

Something like this:

stream create --name DynamicTestStream --definition "http | transform --script='file:/tmp/groovy/#jsonPath(payload,'$.SELECTOR')/transform.groovy' | log"

This errors out as the script is not running through an evaluation step.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right - this won't work. You could possibly have your groovy script be a master that routes to the selector script, e.g. [Including a groovy script in another groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy) or delegate to internal classes or functions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will check out that groovy script approach. However, do you think if I made changes to the included groovy script at runtime those changes would be honored in XD? (after the 60 second refresh)

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to re-evaluate the script location at runtime, it's only evaluated at deployment time. You would need to write a custom transform processor.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I am assuming it is just the evaluation piece that is the issue and that SpringXD/groovy-integration would handle any valid groovy file that it found? or is there some other deploy-time dependency that would prevent such an approach?

Comment: It's a bit more involved than that; the underlying Spring Integration XML parser for the `<int:groovy-script/>` doesn't support it; it's a fixed resource (loaded into the `RefreshableResourceScriptSource` at initialization time). Re-evaluating it at runtime for each message would require a bunch of infrastructure changes. In the meantime to get it to work, you might have to subclass `GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor` and override the `getScriptSource()` method to return a different `ScriptSource` based on the message.

Comment: But @David's suggestion is probably easier.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. In my scenario i potentially have a large number of dedicated transformations - so trying to find the best approach to scale this properly. Leveraging the groovy script for it's easy of deployment and versatility seems like a good fit - given that changes are required often in our business.