# Java called groovy script (with evaluate) and return error

Tags: java, groovy, evaluate

I spent a lot time finding an answer. I found something like the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy), but it was wrong. This doesn't work for me.
 **Situation**:  
I have 2 groovy scripts and java app. 
*Another.groovy (autotest/sources)*

```
class Another
{
    protected String name="";
    public Another() {}
    public main(String[] args) {}
    public boolean getResult() {return true;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String value) {name=value;}
}
```

*test.groovy (autotest/cases)*

```
evaluate(new File("autotest/sources/Another.groovy"))
import support.tool.AutotestResult;
public class Another2 extends Another
{
    public Another2()
    {
        this.setName(this.name+"N");
    }
    public AutotestResult run()
    {
        return new AutotestResult(this.name+"123",this.getResult(),null,null)
    }
}
Another2 a = new Another2()
a.run()
```

Java class called "test.groovy"

```
String[] paths = {"autotest\\cases\\test.groovy"};
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(paths);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("args",null);
System.out.println(((AutotestResult)gse.run("test.groovy", binding)).toJSON());
```

It works perfectly if Another.groovy and test.groovy are in the same folder. But if Another.groovy is in another folder it does not work. Java returned error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/.../autotest/cases/test.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class Another 
 @ line 6, column 1.
   public class Another2 extends Another
   ^
```

So I have questions:

- Can some help with advice?
- Is it possible do (Class from one script extends class from another script which somewhere)?
- Is there another way may be?

PS. Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved with import
**Solution**:

1. Change GroovyScriptEngine class to GroovyShell class
2. Using CompilerConfiguration class and setClassPath("root folder")
3. Add package and import to scripts

*Another.groovy (autotest/sources)*

```
package sources
public class Another
{
    protected String name="AnotherNama";
    public Another() {}
    public main(String[] args) {}
    public boolean getResult() {return true;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String value) {name=value;}
}
```

*test.groovy (autotest/cases)*

```
package cases

import support.tool.AutotestResult;
import sources.Another

public class Another2 extends Another
{
    public Another2()
    {
        this.setName(this.name+"N");
    }
    public AutotestResult run()
    {
        return new AutotestResult(this.name+"123",this.getResult(),null,null)
    }
}
Another2 a = new Another2()
a.run()
```

Java code:

```
CompilerConfiguration config=new CompilerConfiguration();
config.setClasspath("autotest");
config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ImportCustomizer());
GroovyShell shell=new GroovyShell(config);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("args",null);
System.out.println(((AutotestResult)shell.run(new File("autotest/cases/test.groovy"),new ArrayList())).toJSON());
```