# unable to resolve class when calling a class' method from a script through a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job where as part of the build action I am executing a groovy script, say script **A**. From within **script A** I am trying to execute method of **Test1**. Both the files **A.groovy** and **Test1.groovy** are in the same directory.
I am getting `"unable to resolve class"` error whenever I run the job.

**A.groovy**

```
println "****************** TEST : START  *******************************"

println " Environment Variable value is : "
new Test1().printEnv()

println "****************** TEST : END  *******************************"
```

I am using Groovy 2.3.6.

**Test1.groovy**

```
class Test1{

def printEnv(){

println "****************** TEST inside Test1.groovy : START  *******************************"

println "****************** TEST inside Test1.groovy : END  *******************************"
} 

}
```

**Error :**

```
unable to resolve class Test1
```

**NOTE :** When I execute my script from outside jenkins then this works. Its only when I try to execute it through Jenkins that it is unable to find class Test1.

I am very much confused with this behavior.
There are many posts out there that discuss how to resolve the `"unable to resolve class Test1"` error. but none seem to be applicable to my case as the call is fine when its made from outside the Jenkins.

I believe I have provided all the info I could. Still, please feel free to ask for more info, if the need arises.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904699/2915738 this post helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jenkins pipelines, you'll need to load your secondary groovy file. You can find the documentation on how you can use groovy source files into a pipeline [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script).

In your case, you could do something like:

A.groovy

```
def test1 = load 'Test1.groovy'
test1.printEnv()
```

Test1.groovy

```
class Test1 {
  def printEnv() {
    // TODO
  }
}
return new Test1()
```

Note the `return` in Test1.groovy explained in the documentation.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not executing a pipeline script. Its not pipeline as code that I'm following. I'm just executing my groovy script from inside my job. I have specified the script file location under the subsection "Execute Groovy Script" subsection of "Build" section.