# Including initializations from different groovy scripts

Tags: groovy

Following on

- [Including a groovy script in another groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy/9154553)
- [Groovy include new Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618324/groovy-include-new-groovy-script)

what I want (different from above) is to do initialization based on *different* conditions, say `dev`, or `prod`, etc (given from environment variables). There are many parameters to change so I put them in a set. However, I'm just unable to make my groovy scripts working. Here is what I've tried so far:

File `sets.dev.groovy`:

```
def somename = 'abc'
def v = [
        set1: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York", hobby:"Singing"],
        set2: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York", hobby:"Singing"],
    ]

return this.class
```

File `main.groovy`:

```
def stage = 'dev' // should be given from environment instead
def ss = evaluate(new File("sets."+ stage + ".groovy"))
println ss // .v.set2.city
// def s = new sets() X: No such property: somename for class: sets
println ss.newInstance().somename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.groovy

```
def shell = new GroovyShell()

def stage = 'dev' // should be given from environment instead
def ss = shell.evaluate(new File("sets."+ stage + ".groovy"))

println ss.somename
println ss.v.set2.city
```

sets.dev.groovy

```
//note - there is no `def` to make variable declared on class level 

somename = 'abc'

v = [
        set1: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York", hobby:"Singing"],
        set2: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York", hobby:"Singing"],
    ]

return this
```

`groovy main.groovy` prints

```
abc
New York
```